# Number Theory: m>1000, m ends in 007, m is relatively prime to n

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be a positive integer. Prove that there exists a positive integer $m > 1000$ with the following two properties: $m$'s last 3 digits are 007, and $m$ is relatively prime to $n$.
I know that I should first solve the case that $n$ is relatively prime to 1000 and then try to reduce the second case to the first but I don't really know how to do that. 
ALso I know that I can express $m$ as $1000k+007$.

Comment: do any numbers always divide numbers of this form ?

Comment: Can't you just find a prime ending in $007$? Are there any other restrictions on $n$?

Comment: Dirichlet's theorem?

Comment: @platty I can't just use a prime, because $n$ can be any integer so $m$ changes according to $n$. If $m$ was just a prime, then if $n$ was a multiple of $m$ it wouldn't work

Comment: if there aren't constant factors then just look for when the divisors of N can't divide into the arithmetic sequence.

Comment: Primes Are Forever, even [James Bond primes](https://oeis.org/A193552).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.  Having the last three digits  of $m$ be $007$ means $m \equiv 7 \pmod {1000}$  As long as $n$ has no factors of $2$ or $5$ you can just form a set of congruences $m \equiv 1 \pmod p$ where $p$ ranges over the primes that divide $n$.  That set of congruences along with $m \equiv 7 \pmod {1000}$ has a solution and you are done.  I leave patching up the cases where $2$ or $5$ divides $n$ to you.

Answer (score -1):

As Lord Shark has pointed, Dirichlet's theorem implies that there are infinitely many primes that end with $007$. Choose one greater than $n$.

Actually, the series
$$\sum_{p\text{ prime that ends with $007$}}\frac 1p$$
diverges.